# Yesod fails to install in OSX 10.6.8 with Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0

Tags: macos, haskell, yesod

I can't install yesod.
Doing a cabal install yesod-bin or cabal install yesod fails because it
fails to build shakespeare.

I tried with all versions of shapeare >= 2.0, as required by yesod-bin.
Below are all outputs.

My environment:

```
OS X 10.6.8, Xcode 3.2
Haskell-platform 2014.2.0.0
ghc-7.8.3
cabal-install 1.22.4.0 using version 1.22.3.0 of the Cabal library.
```

This corresponds to a fresh install of the HP, ghc, and cabal I did
before trying to install yesod.

The developer of Shakespeare suspects that be a bug of HP and suggested I
try a clean install of GHC as explained in
http://www.stackage.org/install#mac-os-x
However, the bindist available there doesn't work with my OS 10.6.8

I have a large screen output from those trials that you can check on the
Shakespeare github page corresponding to the thread I started there
https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/issues/156

If you prefer, I can paste it here as well.

I already looked on the yesodweb page, sent a mail to the Haskell mailing list, to the Shakespeare developer and googled around. Anybody here that faced (and solved?) this same issue? or that could reproduce it?

I also asked the Shakespeare developer for help on hack a fix on that library. Not sure yet if that is an easy task though. Still waiting for his reply on that.

Thanks in advance.
MA

EDIT: Solved!

The quickstart from the yesod site wouldn't work as I said at the beginning of this thread because the shakespeare package didn't get built.
That's because those steps suggest installing yesod-bin globally and only
afterwards start the sandbox.
Reversing those steps does the work.
More concretely, what I did was

```
mkdir yesod
cd yesod
wget https :// www.stackage.org/lts/cabal.config
cabal update
cabal install alex happy (actually I had these already installed)
cabal sandbox init
cabal install network 
cabal install primitive-0.6 (idem)
cabal install yesod-bin
```

And at this point shakespeare built fine and yesod got installed. I went then further and did

```
export PATH=./.cabal-sandbox/bin/:$PATH
```

in order to get yesod running:

```
yesod init --bare
cabal install -j --enable-tests --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goal (probably not necessary; followed blindly init's suggestion)
cabal install --run-tests
yesod devel
```

That lead to a minor configuring of FirstWebServer-0.0.0..., which triggered a recompile of a few libraries and a rebuild of the application and finally a working Welcome Yesod page at localhost:3000

More details on the Haskell-cafe mailing list under the thread
https: // mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2015-June/120192.html

Comment: All the errors are the same, `Loading package parsec-3.1.5 ... : can't load .so/.DLL for: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/lib/parsec-3.1.5/libHSparsec-3.1.5-ghc7.8.3.dylib (dlopen(/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/lib/parsec-3.1.5/libHSparsec-3.1.5-ghc7.8.3.dylib, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libHStext-1.1.0.0-ghc7.8.3.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/lib/parsec-3.1.5/libHSparsec-3.1.5-ghc7.8.3.dylib
Reason: image not found)` Looks like an issue with the rpath for parsec, as a workaround you might try globally unregistering and then reinstalling it.

Comment: The solution I posted is likely not the only one. Others in the Haskell-cafe thread suggested alternative approaches that might work as well. Wrt your comment, all I can say is that initially it fail specifically complaining about shakespeare not being built. That I could confirm myself by explcitly trying to build all its versions >= 2.0.2.